# Greek letters do not function inside tabular even with dollar sign

Tags: tables, greek

I am trying to use Greek letters inside a tabular-table, but it does not work. Underneath is the sourcecode and error report. Does anyone know how to fix this?

source code (relevant source only):

```
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c |}
\hline
Klein & Groß & Sprechweise & \LaTeX{}-Schreibweise\\
\hline
\hline
$ \alpha $ & $ \Alpha $ & Alpha & \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Error report:
! Undefined control sequence [in line with the dollar signs]

Comment: There is no `\Alpha` command defined

Comment: Α (capital alpha) is `A`. Some goes for all Greek letters that are the same as Roman ones. Even ο (lower-case omicron)

Comment: By the way, if you're trying to use this to teach or display the whole Greek alphabet, it's a bad idea. I learnt this myself the hard way. Upper case Greek letters that LaTeX does provide, like `\Sigma` and `\Pi`, will be upright, while the lower case ones it provides will be italic

Comment: Except with a `Frenchmath` or `upright` option for some packages (`fourier, kpfonts, txmath,…` ).

Comment: I really don't like what's implied here. While the *glyphs* for A and Alpha are (mostly?) the same, the *meaning* is completely different, so, out-of-the-box, it's not semantic markup. There really ought to be a complete, self-consistent, set of commands for *all* the Greek letters, independent of whatever their glyphs may look like.

Comment: `\providecommand*{\Alpha}{A}`

Answer (score 5):

As described in the comments to your question the capital version of the greek letter alpha is identical to capital a (A). Thus, there is no LaTeX command for this letter as it is already defined by `A`.

The set of greek letters that do not have a special command for their capital representation is `Alpha (A), Beta (B), Epsilon (E), Zeta (Z), Eta (E), Iota (I), Kappa (K), Mu (M), Nu (N), Omicron (O), Rho (P), Tau (T), Upsilon (Y) and Chi (X)`.

To make your code compile simply replace `\Alpha` with `A`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c |}
    \hline
    Klein & Groß & Sprechweise & \LaTeX{}-Schreibweise\\
    \hline
    \hline
    $ \alpha $ & $ A $ & Alpha & \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```